# Хранение файлов в json и многоязычность

Tags: android, json

```js
{
  "name": "Вася",       
  "surname": "Петров",
  "age": 35,          
  "contry" : "file:///android_asset/Europa-Albania.png"
}
```

Приложение на двух языках. values-en и values-ru созданы. 
Можно ли в поле значение вместо "Вася" вписывать ссылку на строковый ресурс? Если нельзя, то, пожалуйста, подскажите как по другому это организовать.

Comment: Вы этот джейсон откуда берете? Сами генерите на девайсе или с сервера приходит?

Comment: Сама. В папке assets

Comment: скорей всего будет оптимальным в этом же джейсоне хранить значения под обе локали. name_ru, name_en и тд.

Comment: @АндроидАндроид, если языков мало, то да. А если их 45?

Comment: А я правильно догадываюсь, что этот json используется страницей, загруженной в `WebView`, по ссылке вида `file:///android_asset/...`?

Comment: не для Web. Просто ImageView

Comment: Не знаю зачем Вам json, но в любом случае имена можно поместить в [`<string-array>`](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/string-resource#StringArray) (для удобства имена в один, фамилии в другой), а в json записать индекс имени в этом массиве. Потом, получать из ресурсов массив и по индексу брать имя. `<string-array>` локализуются так же как и `<string>`

Comment: Ещё вариант поместить json-файлы в `res/raw` и их копии для других языков в `raw-ru, raw-en, ...` и т.д. Способ чтения будет несколько другой, но нужный перевод будет выбран автоматически. Или вообще в string-ресурсы их записать

Answer (score 0):

Стандартных средств для такого рода интернационализации нет.
Можно придумать что-то свое, типа:

```
{
  "name": "#first_name_vasily",       
  "surname": "#last_name_petrov",
  "age": 35,
  "contry" : "file:///android_asset/Europa-Albania.png"
}
```

После парсинга делать пост-обработку, если строка начинается с `#`, то искать строковый ресурс с таким именем и заменять.

```
private fun getResIdForName(name: String):Int {
    val resId = resources.getIdentifier(name, "string", packageName)
    return if (resId == 0) R.string.unknown else resId
}
```